# Power BI or SQL for pulling data from a Sharepoint server

Tags: sql, excel, sharepoint, powerbi

Our org maintains data on Sharepoint. My task is to pull data from Excel worksheets and summarize into reports. These Excel files are project estimates, and go back 7-8 years. Cells have common labels but random locations on the worksheets. The magic idea is that reports can be created dynamically by filtering or queries, pulling crawled data from these files on Sharepoint.

At a very high level, should I go down the path of Power BI, SQL, both or none to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and should become more relevant as more organizations start using `SharePoint` and consequently raise the automation level, which leads to dealing with legacy data and harmonization of meta-data.

Recently, I had success with a similar exercise, except it was for `XML` files. The approach was to

1. Create a scheduled task: call `PowerShell`, collect raw data into XML files.
2. Collected XML files are parsed in `SQLServer` with a job that iterates files and extracts data using `T-SQL`.
3. Parsed data is written into data model tables, `SQL` views are created, and passed onto `PowerBI`, where data is displayed and updated as needed.

Separately, I used `PowerShell` and `Python` to parse `Excel` files: both were manageable, but `Python` package implementations looked a bit more familiar.

I am sure there are multiple paths to this top. What would you do differently?

P.S. calling code withing large Excel `macro` files would be a whole another topic: it was very slow, ~90 sec per file